# How to filter on data in fields once a mysqli query has been called.

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

I have a table that contain attachments with various properties stored in columns, the two I am trying to filter on is "Type" and "Status"

The "Type" column can have several values like "Type1, Type2, Type3, ...etc."

The "Status" column can have several values like "Approved, Disapproved, Under Review, ...etc."

I would like to be able to filter the results in the mysqli array, after making the query, to count the results of how many "Type1" are "Approved", how many "Type2" are "Disapproved", ...etc.

Here is the query to the database and where I am stuck.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE $COORDT = 'T'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $resultarray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 ///Need Help Here!
 $Type1App_cnt = $resultarray->num_rows OF TYPE1 AND APPROVED;
 $Type1DisApp_cnt = $resultarray->num_rows OF TYPE1 AND DISAPPROVED;
 $Type2App_cnt = $resultarray->num_rows OF TYPE2 AND APPROVED;
 etc...
```

Can this be done? I am not wanting to build separate queries for each combination of "Type" and "Status" if I don't have too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either create multiple queries or loop through the results of the query and count the records of each type.

Comment: What would be the most efficient way of doing that loop?

Comment: You can have an assoc array of results where the keys are the types and status like $results['Type1']['Approved'] and have the values be the count, so the loop would be a foreach and then the count can be done in one line of code